# Calculate grand mean and participant mean RT to perform exclusions

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to exclude the entire data set of a participant, when the overall mean RT of said participant is more than 2 SDs away from the grand mean, regardless of trial or factor.

```
Subj Trial     factor   rt 
1     1        Early    324 
1     2        Late     405 
1     3        Early    1093 
1     4        Late     738 
1     5        Early    310
1     6        Early    389 
1     7        Late     1050
1     8        Late     782
1     9        Late     513 
1    10        Early    401
2     1        Early    920 
2     2        Late     1230
2     3        Early    1509
2     4        Late     1456
2     5        Early    2341
2     6        Early    900
2     7        Late     1100
2     8        Late     1329
2     9        Late     1189
2    10        Early    1030 
3     1        Early    999
3     2        Late     499
3     3        Early    1003 
3     4        Late     389
3     5        Early    356
3     6        Early    365
3     7        Late     1234
3     8        Late     345
3     9        Late     300 
3    10        Early    402
```

So far I got this to calculate participants mean rt and sd and

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Subj) %>% 
  summarise(N=n(), 
            avgrt=mean(rt),
            sd_sub = sd(rt),
            min = min(rt),
            median=median(rt),
            max = max(rt)
            )
```

And this to calculate the Grand Mean and SD.

```
data_clean <- df %>% 
summarise(grandmean=mean(avgrt),
          sd_clean = sd(sd_sub)
          )
```

However, I don't know to continue from here... How can I create a filter that allows me to compare participants mean RT to the Grand Mean and exclude them if it's 2SD away from it?

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `dplyr` solution does what is asked for.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(rt), sd = sd(rt)) %>%
  group_by(Subj) %>%
  mutate(m = mean(rt),
         within = (m >= mean - 2*sd) & (m <= mean + 2*sd)) %>%
  filter(within) %>%
  select(-mean, -sd, -m, -within)
```

Comment: Thanks @Rui Barradas